# Change UIButton image from another View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have two View Controllers, `aController` and `bController`. I have a button in `aController`. Now I want to change the button image from  `bController`. I created a method named `chageButtonImg` in `aController` and I called `chageButtonImg` method from `bController` after some functionalities to change the `UIButton` image. I called it but the button image is not updating.

What can I do to change the button image?

Comment: If the bController is already loaded then you can use NSNotificationCenter to call a specific method there you can change the background image of the button. If it will be called fro the aController then pass a boolean variable based on the boolean you can set the image

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the button image like that the issue is that when your views of bController appears than all the ui elements in aController automatically get set to null.So to implement this functionality pass the image in a variable to aController and than in viewwillAppear change the image of button

Comment: Actually i am in aController when  i am trying to  change the UIButton image .bController is working as Background task.

Comment: This should be easy just post your code so we can see where did you make a mistake

Comment: in bController:                                                                                                            if(count==[myArr count]){
      HomeController *myH=[[HomeController alloc] init];
      [myH songFinished:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imButton.png"]];
       return;                                                                                          
 }

Comment: In aController:                                                                                                  -(void)songFinished:(UIImage *)icon{
  //  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton"];
    [_playAndPauseButton setImage:icon];
   }

Comment: here HomeController  is aController.

Comment: Edit your question and post the full controller code there :)

Answer (score 0):

**Just pass the image name to second view controller through NSString:**

```
- (IBAction)collagescreen:(id)sender
{
    viewcontrollerB *bcontroller=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"collage"];
    bcontroller.string=@"imagename here.jpg"
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**ViewController B.m file you can do like this**

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:YourString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public property imageName in aController having button.
and in bController ---

```
 if(count==[myArr count]){ 
   HomeController *myH=[[HomeController alloc] init]; 
   [myH.imageName = @"imButton.png"; 
   return; 
}
```

In a Controller ----
Implement custom getter for button

```
- (UIButton *) playAndPauseButton {

  UIImage *img = nil;
  if([_imageName isEqualToString:@“”]) {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton"]; 
   } else {
     img = [UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]
  }
  [_playAndPauseButton setImage:icon]; 
  return  _playAndPauseButton;
}
```

Comment: I don not know your VC state in navigation but if all set then it will work.